# Since JavaScript is single-threaded, how are web workers in HTML5 doing multi-threading?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I've been reading about web workers in HTML5, but I know JavaScript is single-threaded.

How are web workers doing multi-threaded work then? or how are they simulating it if it's not truly multi-threaded?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

As several comments have already pointed out, Workers really are multi-threaded.

Some points which may help clarify your thinking:

- JavaScript is a language, it doesn't define a threading model, it's not necessarily single threaded
- Most browsers have historically been single threaded (though that is changing rapidly: [IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/11/ie8-and-loosely-coupled-ie-lcie.aspx), [Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html), [Firefox](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Content_Processes)), and most JavaScript implementations occur in browsers
- Web Workers are not part of JavaScript, they are a browser feature which can be accessed through JavaScript

Comment: That is where I was missing the distinction, it's with the browser spec and not the JavaScript language.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard I think the main issue is that the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) can't easily be made multi-threaded, and JavaScript is commonly used for DOM manipulation.  But the DOM is not JavaScript.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard javascript *still is single threaded*, even with web workers. Web workers don't make javascript multi-threaded in any way that it wasn't before, think about it like this: you're essentially starting another single-threaded process and communicating with it, like you would be able to in node.js for example. The javascript in the browser is single-threaded, and the javascript in the worker is single-threaded, but they're able to communicate to each other through a thin channel.

Comment: this is how I understood: browser uses a single thread (that has javascript code) to render DOM and handle related eventloop (which can also contain javascript code to do non-dom things like adding two numbers) but we can use worker through which browser can do only non-dom (javascript still) code. Then, we can synchronize data between the two (insert multi-threading concepts here). 
So, paraphrasing @James Drinkard, _"browser handles DOM in single-thread javascript"_; we can still have other javascript threads that _dont touch the DOM_

Answer (score 25):

A bit late, but I just asked myself the same question and I came up with the following answer:
**Javascript in browsers is always single-threaded**, and a fundamental consequence is that "concurrent" access to variables (the principal headache of multithreaded programming) is actually not concurrent; this is true **with the exception of webworkers**, which are actually run in separate threads **and concurrent access to variables must be dealt with in a somewhat explicit way**.

I am not a JavaScript ninja, but I too was convinced that JavaScript in browser is provided as a single threaded process, without paying much attention to whether it was true or to the rationale behind this belief.
A simple fact that supports this assumption is that when programming in JavaScript you **don't have to care about concurrent access to shared variables**. Every developer, without even thinking of the problem, writes code as if every access to a variable is consistent.
In other words, you don't need to worry about the so called [Memory model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)).

Actually there is no need of looking at WebWorkers to involve parallel processing in JavaScript. Think of an (asynchronous) AJAX request. And think how carelessly you would handle concurrent access to variables:

```
var counter = 0;

function asyncAddCounter() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      counter++;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/a/remote/resource", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

asyncAddCounter();
counter++;
```

What is the value of `counter` at the end of the process? It is `2`.
It doesn't matter that it is read and written "concurrently", it will never result in a `1`. This means that access to `counter` is always consistent.
If two threads where really accessing the value concurrently, they both could start off by reading `0` and both write `1` in the end.

In browsers, the actual data-fetching of a remote resource is hidden to the developer, and its inner workings are outside the scope of the JavaScript API (what the browser let's you control in terms of JavaScript instructions). As far as the developer is concerned, the *result* of the network request is processed by the main thread.
In short, the actual carrying out of the *request* is not visible, but the invocation of the *callback* (handling the result by custom JavaScript code) is executed by the main thread.
Possibly, if it wasn't for the webworkers, the term "multithreading" wouldn't ever enter the Javascript world.

The execution of the request and the *asynchronous* invocation of the callback is actually achieved by using **event loops**, not multithreading. This is true for several browsers and obviously for Node.js. The following are some references, in some cases a bit obsolete, but I guess that the main idea is still retained nowadays.

- Firefox: [Concurrency model and Event Loop - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)
- Chrome uses [libevent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libevent) in certain OS.
- IE: [Understanding the Event Model (Internet Explorer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533023(v=vs.85).aspx)

This fact is the reason why JavaScript is said to be [Event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) but not multithreaded.
Notice that JavaScript thus allows for *asynchronous* idioms, but not *parallel* execution of JavaScript code (outside webworkers). The term *asynchronous* just denotes the fact that the result of two instructions might be processed in scrambled order.

As for WebWorkers, *they are* JavaScript APIs that give a developer control over a multithreaded process.
As such, they provide explicit ways to handle concurrent access to shared memory (read and write values in different threads), and this is done, among the others, in the following ways:

- you push data to a web worker (which means that the new thread reads data) by structured clone: [The structured clone algorithm - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm). Essentially there is no "shared" variable, instead the new thread is given a fresh copy of the object.
- you push data to a web worker by transferring ownership of the value: [Transferable - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable). This means that the just one thread can read its value at any time.
- as for the results returned by the web workers (how they "write"), the main thread access the results when prompted to do so (for instance with the instruction `thisWorker.onmessage = function(e) {console.log('Message ' + e.data + ' received from worker');}`). It must be by means of the usual Event Loop, I must suppose.
- the main thread and the web worker access a truly shared memory, the `SharedArrayBuffer`, which is thread-safely accessed using the `Atomic` functions. I found this clearly exposed in this article: [JavaScript: From Workers to Shared Memory](http://lucasfcosta.com/2017/04/30/JavaScript-From-Workers-to-Shared-Memory.html)
- note: webworkers cannot access the DOM, which is truly shared!

Comment: Much better, complete and explained answer, and should be the accepted correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

You spawn a .js file as a "worker", and it runs processes in a separate thread. You can pass JSON data back and forth between it and the "main" thread. Workers don't have access to certain things like the DOM, though.

So if, say, you wanted to solve complicated math problems, you could let the user enter things into the browser, pass those variables off to the worker, let it do the computation in the background while in the main thread you let the user do other things, or show a progress bar or something, and then when the worker's done, it passes the answer back, and you print it to the page. You could even do multiple problems asynchronously and pass back the answers out of order as they finish. Pretty neat!

Comment: JSON (Javascript Object Notation) is stored in strings, so you should say that you can transfer strings.
According to this question, postMessage can send clones of various objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761968/detect-whether-postmessage-can-send-objects
According to the MDN article (which doesn't mention that only strings was a thing), you can transfer certain objects (which is faster than copying): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage
Based on this, it should be possible to link Workers together into a pipeline using MessagePorts...

Answer (score 2):

Actually the main confusion, I think here, comes that people are finding clever ways to do things concurrently. If you think about it JavaScript is clearly not multithreaded and yet we have ways to do things in parallel, so what is going on?

Asking the right question is what will bring the answer here. Who is responsible for the threads? There is one answer above, saying that JS is just a language, not a threading model. Completely true!JavaScript has nothing to do with it. The responsibility falls on V8. Check this link for more information -> https://v8.dev/
So V8 is allowing a single thread per JS Context, which means, no matter how hard you try, spawning a new thread is simply impossible. Yet people spawn so-called workers and we get confused. For this to be answered, I ask you the following. Is it possible to maybe start 2 V8 and both of them to interpret some JS code? Precisely the solution to our problem. Workers communicate with messages because their context is different. They are other things that don't know anything about our context, therefore they need some information that comes in the form of a message.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that claimed that "JavaScript is a language, it doesn't define a threading model, it's not necessarily single-threaded" is directly copy-pasted from a medium article... and it confuses without solving the doubt.

It's not necessarily single-threaded, like all other languages. YES... BUT

Javascript is a LANGUAGE meant for Single-threaded programming, and that is the beauty of it and makes it simple and easy to implement.
It is designed around a single Call stack.
Maybe in the future, with new implementations, it will become a Language for multi-threaded programming... but for now, Mehhhhhh.

The Node V8 is still single-threaded, yet it achieves multi-threaded capabilities by creating worker threads on LIBUV which is written in C++.

Same way, even though Javascript is not meant for Multithreading you can achieve limited multithreading by using Browser APIs.

Every time you open a TAB on a browser, it creates a new thread, and the process is the same with web workers.

It works internally BUT does not have access to any window objects.

Yes, People may call it Multithreaded if it makes em Happy,
But in 2021 the Answer is
"JS is meant for Single-threaded programming,(or a single-threaded language) but limited multi-threading can be achieved by using Browser APIs such as Web Workers"

Answer (score 1):

The browser kicks of a thread with the javascript you want to execute. So its a real thread, with this web workers thing, your js is no longer single-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

As we are all aware, JavaScript is single-threaded: all code is queued and executed in a sequence.

Using Web Workers, we can run JavaScript processes concurrently (or at least, as close to concurrently as this language allows). The primary benefit of this approach is to handle the manipulation of data in background threads without interfering with the user-interface.

**Using web worker:**

Web Workers allow you to run JavaScript in parallel on a web page, without blocking the user interface.

- Web workers executes in separate thread
- Need to host all the worker code in separate file
- They aren’t automatically garbage collected, So you need to control them.
- To run worker use worker.postMessage(“”);
- To stop worker there are two methods terminate() from caller code
  and close() from Worker itself
- Instantiating a worker will cost some memory.

Web Workers run in an isolated thread. As a result, the code that they execute needs to be contained in a separate file. But before we do that, the first thing to do is create a new Worker object in your main page. The constructor takes the name of the worker script:

```
var worker = new Worker('task.js');
```

If the specified file exists, the browser will spawn a new worker thread, which is downloaded asynchronously. The worker will not begin until the file has completely downloaded and executed. If the path to your worker returns an 404, the worker will fail silently.

After creating the worker, start it by calling the postMessage() method:

```
worker.postMessage(); // Start the worker.
```

***Communicating with a Worker via Message Passing***

Communication between a work and its parent page is done using an event model and the postMessage() method. Depending on your browser/version, postMessage() can accept either a string or JSON object as its single argument. The latest versions of the modern browsers support passing a JSON object.

Below is a example of using a string to pass 'Hello World' to a worker in doWork.js. The worker simply returns the message that is passed to it.

*Main script:*

```
var worker = new Worker('doWork.js'); 
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) { 
  console.log('Worker said: ', e.data); 
}, false); 

 

worker.postMessage('Hello World'); // Send data to our worker.
```

*doWork.js (the worker):*

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) { 

  self.postMessage(e.data); // Send data back to main script 

}, false);
```

When postMessage() is called from the main page, our worker handles that message by defining an onmessage handler for the message event. The message payload (in this case 'Hello World') is accessible in Event.data. This example demonstrates that postMessage() is also your means for passing data back to the main thread. Convenient!

***References:***

[http://www.tothenew.com/blog/multi-threading-in-javascript-using-web-workers/](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/multi-threading-in-javascript-using-web-workers/%E2%80%AF)

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

https://dzone.com/articles/easily-parallelize-jobs-using-0

Comment: Your first link in your references section is dead.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But this still does not answer the main thread question. You mention "Web workers executes in separate thread", but since javascript run in single thread, where does this "separate thread" comes in?