# iFrame parent.postMessage returns string instead of object in IE9

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I have an issue with trying to retrieve an object from an iFrame using postMessage. Essentially, I have an iFrame I am being forced to use to hit a SAML authentication endpoint. The SAML endpoint returns javascript object to the iFrame, which then sends that object to the parent window as part of a `parent.postMessage` event:

```
parent.postMessage(authResponse,"*");
```

In Chrome and newer versions of IE, the parent window event listener snags the object just fine, and we are off and running. However, in IE 9 the iFrame doesn't send the object, it sends a string like `"[Object object]"`.

So of course code that tries to reference object attributes like `authResponse.token` fail. I have looked at the [docs for postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) and I see how you can [detect whether your browser will send an object or a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761968/detect-whether-postmessage-can-send-objects). I also believe that I can't just [look at the contents of the iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript) because it is indeed cross-domain.

I cannot control the contents of the iFrame (have the auth objectsent as a json string, or have the iFrame include some polyfill, etc). So my question is, am I out of options? Can anyone think of a creative hack that might suit?

Thanks!

Comment: If the code expects that IE8 and 9 will accept an object as a parameter to `postMessage()`, then it's just broken. Those browsers simply won't do that.

Comment: @Pointy I believe you are right, and I haven't thought of a way around it. If you would like to post as an answer, I'll accept! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older versions of Internet Explorer that support `postMessage()` simply don't support object serialization through the interface. Even older versions of Firefox didn't support that, but because independent browsers tend to update themselves aggressively that's not a practical concern.

If you're dealing with code that assumes it can use `postMessage()` to transmit objects, then it just won't work in IE before IE10.